# Can't install microsoft office 2013 32bit

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-office, windows-8.1

I removed an uninstalled 64bit of Office because SAGE ACT will not work with it and the installer for 32bit just hangs.

I get a 1704 error when I run the installer and I say yes.

```
Error 1704. An installation for Microsoft Office 64-bit components 2013 is currently suspended. You must undo the changes by the installation to continue. Do you want to undo those changes?
```

I say yes, it installs then gets hung in the setup. I've let it run all night too.

I've disabled AV software and cleaned the registry and rebooted.

Comment: Rebooted yet? Just to be sure...

Comment: Yep. Several times. ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer from the business that helped me out:

http://blog.solidshellsecurity.com/2014/03/13/microsoft-office-2013-volume-x64x86-installation-new-windows-8-1-pro-pc-hangs-repeatedly/

What happened is the installed got glitched. So you have to kill 4 of the processes and it continues.

Answer (score 1):

Step one is to ensure you have removed the 64bit version correctly. Microsoft provide a FixIt tool for your use [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739501).

From this point Microsoft support suggests the following for this error, which seems to have solved the problem for several people there:

> Try to install Office 2013 and check for results. If the issue persists, then restart computer in Windows Clean boot following these steps and then install Office 2013:
>
> - Press the Windows + R key on the keyboard.
> - In the Run windows type MSCONFIG and click Ok.
> - Click the Boot tab and uncheck Safe Boot option.
> - On the General tab, click to select the option Selective Startup, and then click to clear the option Load startup items check box.
> - On the Services tab, click to select the Hide all Microsoft services check box, and then click Disable all.
> - On the Startup tab, click Open Task Manager. In the Task Manager window under startup tab, right click on each startup item which are enabled and select Disable.
> - Click OK, and then click Restart.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/error-1704/ef85973c-17a5-4124-94ff-c1c22978a7a3)

EDIT: As you can imagine I cannot test if this method works as I am not suffering the same issue. So do let us know the result.

UPDATE: There are older examples of this situation which might help you provide an answer. This has come from a Microsoft support post on an older version of Office, which you can find  [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/228655)

Comment: No go on any of those :(

Comment: @FrankThornton | From what I can understand this error is a system restart issue, which has been around for a while. I have edited my answer to include an older example and possible solutions which you might want to follow.

Comment: I've restarted several times. Same issue of getting hung on install.

Comment: @FrankThornton | Have you tried ending the install process, scrubbing your system of all Office traces, restarting your system and starting the process again?